# Error SQL in java: Illegal operation on empty result set

Tags: java, sql

I have a problem with an empty result set, which are throwing some errors. But it is working fine as long as it is not empty.

```
String sql = "SELECT M2.fromProfileId, profiles.profileMiniature, profiles.firstName, profiles.lastName, profiles.timeFormat, lastMessages.message, lastMessages.timeStamp " +
                "FROM   (" +
                "       SELECT M1.fromProfileId, " +
                "           max(M1.timeStamp) AS lastMessageTime " +
                "       FROM messages AS M1 " +
                "       WHERE M1.toProfileId = ? " +
                "       GROUP BY M1.fromProfileId " +
                "       ORDER BY max(M1.timeStamp) DESC " +
                "       LIMIT 10 " +//line 60
                "       ) AS M2 " +
                "INNER JOIN messages AS lastMessages " +
                "ON     (" +
                "       lastMessages.timeStamp = M2.lastMessageTime " +
                "AND    lastMessages.fromProfileId = M2.fromProfileId" +
                "       )" +
                "INNER JOIN profiles " +
                "ON M2.fromProfileId = profiles.profileId ";

PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

statement.setString(1, profileId);
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

JSONArray messages = new JSONArray();
while(result.next()){
    JSONObject message = new JSONObject();

    message.put("fromProfileId", result.getString("fromProfileId"));
    message.put("profileMiniature", result.getString("profileMiniature"));
    message.put("firstName", result.getString("firstName"));
    message.put("lastName", result.getString("lastName"));
    message.put("lastMessage", result.getString("message"));
    message.put("lastMessageTime", result.getString("timeStamp"));
    message.put("timeFormat", result.getString("timeFormat"));
    messages.put(message);
}
```

and the error is `Illegal operation on empty result set`. How shall I fix this?

**StackTrace:**

> Illegal operation on empty result set.
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:841)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5656)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5576)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5616)
>   at
>   messages.GetMessages.doGet(GetMessages.java:60)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:534)
>   etc..

Comment: Full stacktrace will be very helpful here

Comment: Hmmm. It could be a bug in the version of MySQL JDBC driver that you're using!

Comment: What are you doing at GetMessages.java line 60 ?

Comment: Ditto as above comment. I too want to know.

Comment: @Xavinou: thats's my java class

Comment: @Woho87 : I want to see the code at line 60

Comment: What's on line 60 of GetMessages? More importantly, is that line in the code extract you've shown us? Because it looks like getString is called on the ResultSet, which shouldn't happen if it is empty; `.next()` should return false if there's no rows. Might indeed by a MySQL driver bug.

Comment: ok line 60 is marked. The code I provided is the class I'm talking about

Comment: Can you give us the exact version of the Connector-J being used?

Comment: @adarshr: mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar

Comment: Don't see any problem with the code. I smell a buggy JDBC driver.

Comment: which drivers are you using for mysql?

Comment: If it is a bug this is a really serious bug. On empty result set? Can I overcome this bug. For instance checking the number of rows?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing anything like that. Just try with an older version of the driver. It might have been introduced only with this version!

Comment: @Woho87 : If there are not many rows returned by the query, you can try to debug step by step, to see exactly what happens.

Comment: @adarshr: Same error with 5.0.8 version and 3.2 version too

Comment: @Xavinau: it is only happening with zero row. I tried now twice

Comment: ok now I know what went wrong. This class what GetContacts and in the GetMessage class I found the line 60 and it was a getString operation that shouldn't be initiated. Thanks guys anyway

Answer (score 2):

I found [many](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Illegal+operation+on+empty+result+set&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&q=site%3amysql.com+%22Illegal+operation+on+empty+result+set%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=5f8640c9233c188f) bugs in MySQL JDBC driver which seem to cause this exception.