# **Illegal operation on empty reult set**

Tags: java

I had to make a Car Rental System Project for an school assignment. The code seems fine to me with no errors but after running it, a dialog box shows up saying 'Illegal operation on empty result set'. I have tried fixing it by twisting the code and even writing it with 'if' and 'while' conditions/loops. I have tagged a picture of the interface along with the error dialog box. Please check them if necessary.

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        jButton2.setEnabled(true);

        try
        {
      OpenConnection();
      String cmodel=(String) cmbModel.getSelectedItem();
      String modelno=txtModel.getText();
      String query="Select * from car where model='"+cmodel+"' and modelno='"+modelno+"';";

      ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
      rs.next();

      String cno= rs.getString("CarNo");
      txtCno.setText(cno);
      String price= rs.getString("RentalPrice");
      txtPrice.setText(price);
      String mfg= rs.getString("MfgDate");
      txtMfg.setText(mfg);
      String dop= rs.getString("DOP");
      txtDop.setText(dop);
      String mileage= rs.getString("Mileage");
      txtMileage.setText(mileage);
      String seat= rs.getString("Seater");
      txtSeater.setText(seat);
      cmbModel.setEditable(false);
      txtModel.setEditable(false);
      txtCno.setEditable(false);
      txtPrice.setEditable(false);
      txtDop.setEditable(false);
      txtMileage.setEditable(false);
      txtSeater.setEditable(false);
      txtMfg.setEditable(false);

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

IMAGE 1:[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E86ip.png)

IMAGE 2:[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL019.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Please make sure first that query return the value in result set. this issue is come when your resultset is empty.**

**Please prefer PreparedStatement insted of Statement.**

**Billow link may help you :** 
[Illegal operation on empty result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133509/illegal-operation-on-empty-result-set)

Comment: I attempted as instructed by others in that post but unfortunately, the problem sustains to be.

Comment: can you please check what comes in your resultset